# run a command when bp is hit in OLLY 1.10

Tags: ollydbg

I would like to automate a process of enabling buttons with `cond bp`.

First, I found that function `user32.EnableWindow` is called from `mfc110u.dll`.

So I went there and set `cond bp` on the second arg of the function.

This `arg2==0` when you want the button to be disabled and `arg2==1` when enabled.

So what I did ?

1. I set `cond bp` with condition `[EBP+8]==0` and now want to run something like this each time the bp is hit:
   **A (EBP+8) DD 1**.
2. I downloaded the plugin `CLBPlus!` and for this plugin is identifier CLBP so final command become: **CLBP A (EBP+8) DD 1**.

But for some reason this does not work. Maybe the command A is not implemented. I downloaded the two another plugins "Command Line v1.10" and "Command Bar v3.20.110" but unfortunately I do not know the identifiers for these plugings.

So any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ODbgScript](http://sourceforge.net/projects/odbgscript/files/English%20Version/) to set conditional breakpoints and perform automated actions when those breakpoints are hit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx Jason for the tip. I tried it before but it did not work. Now I tried it again and hopefuly it seems working. In olly command line when I wrote **A (EBP+8) DD 1** I saw it worked. The syntax for script is **asm eip, "mov eax, ecx"**, so I tried to write **asm (ebp+8), "dd 1"**, but did not work. So I tried **asm ebp+8, "dd 1"** and it seems working. I put conditional breakpoints manualy and constructed this nice dirty code:

START:
asm ebp+8, "dd 1"
run
jmp START

it works nicely. Thanx for the tip again"!